# Conditional file entry using bash

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

say i have a bash while loop

```
while read line
do
    #do stuff here
done < $1
```

I want the entry into the while loop to depend on a comman line argument (e.g. if they type -g it will take their own string instead of taking a file that was entered as a command line argument)

so if they enter put in the terminal

```
./myshellscript thisfile.txt
```

It perform the while loop on the txt file but if they type

```
./myshellscript -g
```

It will ask them for a string (Dont need any help with getting user input) and perform the while loop on the string instead. Anyway of doing this without just copy pasting the while loop inside of an if statement?

Comment: if `$1 == "-g"` then you can do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ "$1" = -g ]
then
    read -p "Enter data: " var
    exec 3< <(echo "$var")
elif [ -r "$1" ]
then
    exec 3<"$1"
else
    echo "Bad argument.  Aborting."
    exit 1
fi


while read line
do
    # do stuff here
    echo Got line=$line
done <&3
exec 3<&-
```

The above code first checks `$1` and then opens a file handle.  If the the first argument is `-g`, it gets input and provides that to the file handle via process substitution (bash or better required).  If, on the other hand, `$1` is a valid file name, it uses that file for the input.  If neither, it prints an error message and exits.  The `while` loop gets its input from the provide file handle.  The last statement closes the file handle.

Comment: Cheers for the help, is there anything inherently special with the exec 3 command or could that be exec (myvarhere) instead of 3?

Comment: @user3462648 File handles are numbers.  0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr.  I chose three so as not to interfere with the others.  Higher digits may also be used.

Comment: Also one more thing why in the line
    exec 3< <(echo "$var") 
are both '<' needed what is the purpose of having both?

Comment: The first `<` for the file redirect.  The second `<` is for "process substitution".  The form `<(...)` provides a file like object that is used as the source for the redirect.

Comment: Opening a new file descriptor is unnecessary; you can simply do `read ... fname` or `fname=$1` as the case may be, then read from `$fname`.